# How to work around the impossibility of accessing the DOM in a chrome extension manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

My company needs an internal non-public chrome extension to go and fetch prices and lead times on suppliers' websites.

Previously, with manifest v2 extensions, I used to, for each product, automatically open a new chrome tab with `chrome.tabs.create()`, and execute a script with `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` which got the info by running a few `querySelector` on the DOM of the target page on the supplier's website.

But with the advent of manifest v3 chrome extension, which is now mandatory as of next January 1st, I cannot access the DOM anymore.

The problem is that I cannot just execute HTTP GET requests from our server, via CURL or something like that, because the vast majority of our suppliers use sophisticated authentification processes that I don't fully know, which require opening a session in a real browser.

Does someone have any idea of working around this problem ?

Thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: There's no such problem, it still works, so you need to add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the DOM on the currently open tab. For example with the use of [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/).
It is only on the "background" page, there is no more DOM due to the use of a service worker (required in the new Manifest V3).

Use `fetch` in your service worker.
Source: [https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#:~:text=Workers%20no%20longer%20provide%20XMLHttpRequest%2C%20but%20instead%20support%20the%20more%20modern%20fetch()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/#:%7E:text=Workers%20no%20longer%20provide%20XMLHttpRequest%2C%20but%20instead%20support%20the%20more%20modern%20fetch()).

```
fetch('https://www.example.com/data.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data));
```

Manifest V3

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self';connect-src 'self' https://www.example.com;"
```

Comment: What would that look like after an element click which changes the dom structure at run time, but is still on same page?

Comment: @jwp You can place the data result in a custom <div> id. So no need to refresh the complete web page.

Comment: Would you please be able to post a complete solution to this? It seems that even Google are unable to provide a simple demo for this in their Git repo, and sadly despite having spent collectively a number of hours (30 mins here and there) trying to piece something together, there's too much confusion from older v2 properties and the new v3 :(